# jQuery Supersized Plugin callback when slideshow finishd

Tags: jquery, callback, slideshow

I am using the Supersized jQuery plugin which makes images fullscreen and also implements a slideshow.  Currently, this plugin does not have a callback for when the slideshow is finished, rather, it just continually repeats.

Is there a way that I could trigger a function after the last slide is shown?

Currently, I have it working to trigger a function when the last slide STARTS to be shown, as I have a setInterval which checks for the "last" class on the slideshow images.  But, this runs the function when that last slide starts, not when it is finished.

Does anyone have ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a .addClass('last'); to my last image then when that was cued up, I fired my function.